# object tracking by python and opencv

Tags: python

my code is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("slow.flv")

ret,frame = cap.read()
r,h,c,w = 250,90,400,125 # simply hardcoded the values
track_window = (c,r,w,h)
roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]
hsv_roi = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_roi, np.array((0., 60.,32.)), 
np.array((180.,255.,255.)))
roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi],[0],mask,[180],[0,180])
cv2.normalize(roi_hist,roi_hist,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )

while(1):
    ret ,frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv],[0],roi_hist,[0,180],1)
        ret, track_window = cv2.meanShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)
        x,y,w,h = track_window
        img2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255,2)
        cv2.imshow("img2",img2)
        k = cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
        else:
            cv2.imwrite(chr(k)+".jpg",img2)
    else:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

the error is:

> File "objecttracking.py", line 10, in 
>       roi = frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that `cap.read()` is returning a `None` for the value you're storing to `frame`. Thus when you try and index into `frame` with `frame[r:r+h, c:c+w]` you get an error.